# Dank Mono isn't working on VSCode on Ubuntu

Tags: json, fonts, visual-studio-code, settings

I downloaded the latest release of Dank Mono, and I installed it on Ubuntu 18.04 using Font Manager.

I see it installed on my system, but when I use it in VSCode and Hyper.js Terminal Settings, they do not behave correctly. I have ligatures enabled and before that `Fira Code` worked just fine. **So, why is my font so different than the site? How do I fix it?**

Here are my JSON Settings in VSCode:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Dank Mono",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Dank Mono",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.fontWeight": "600",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
    "html.format.wrapLineLength": 80,
    "vsicons.projectDetection.autoReload": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "City Lights",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "city-lights-icons-vsc-light"
}
```

Comment: On a troubleshooting attempt it appears my theme doesn't support the ligatures. I use city lights, as you can see.What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the font and then install it, but just before you do, hit the `info` button right beside the `install` button(on Linux) and then verify the name of the font. After installing and adding `editor.fontFamily: <the-name-specified-by-font>` to your `settings.json` file restart the editor.